# How to plot a regression line in each of the subplots of a plotmatrix in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, regression, scatter-plot

I have a scatter matrix (plotmatrix)

```
p1 = plotmatrix(M);
```

But then I need to plot a regression line and the R-squared in each subplot on the upper-section of the figure. Any ideas on how to do this??

Something like corrplot.m, however I have an older version of Matlab...

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a version of [`corrplot.m` on the File Exchange](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/35674-corrplot/content/cp/corrplot.m), which "Plots correlation coefficients with confidence limits." This sounds a lot like the version of [`corrplot` in the MATLAB Econometrics Toolbox](http://www.mathworks.com/help/econ/corrplot.html).

Possibly you can use `corrcoeff` manually and plot the lines manually on the subplots.  To get the handles of the subplots created with `plotmatrix`, reference the long output syntax:

```
[H,AX,BigAx,P,PAx] = plotmatrix(...) returns a matrix of handles
to the objects created in H, a matrix of handles to the individual
subaxes in AX, a handle to big (invisible) axes that frame the
subaxes in BigAx, a matrix of handles for the histogram plots in
P, and a matrix of handles for invisible axes that control the
histogram axes scales in PAx.
```

Since you just need the axis handles to do this, just output `AX` and whatever else is needed:

```
[p1,AX] = plotmatrix(M)
```

This will allow you to plot on each subplot's axis:

```
for ii=1:size(AX,1),
    for jj=1:size(AX,2),
        if ii == jj, continue; end
        hold(AX(ii,jj),'on')
        plot(AX(ii,jj),...)
    end
end
```

Comment: I see, hmm... it might be necessary to use `corrcoef` manually and plot a line manually on your subplots.  Sorry.

Comment: @OliverAmundsen I think you can get them directly from `plotmatrix`.  See the updated answer.

Comment: It works but deletes the previous dots... I do e.g.  for ii=1:size(AX,1),
    for jj=1:size(AX,2),
        if ii == jj
            continue
        end
    hold on
    plot(AX(ii,jj),1,1,'r*')
    end
end

Comment: @OliverAmundsen When you run `hold`, you also have to specify an axis with the functional form:  `hold(AX(ii,jj),'on')`.  BTW, I'll add your code to the answer.